# Namespce OneTimeTearDownAttirbute () and OneTimeSetUpttirbute () does not exist in NUnit.Framework showing error in auto generated specflow(.cs) file

Tags: nunit, specflow, xamarin.uitest

Facing build error The type or namespace name "OneTimeSetUpAttribute" and "OneTimeTearDownAttribute" doesnot exist

Xamarin.UITest-Version 3.0.0
Nunit- Version 2.6.4
NunitTestAdapter- Version 2.0.0 
Specflow -Version 2.1.0.0[image]

Answer (score 0):

`OneTimeSetUpAttribute` didn't exist until NUnit 3.0. You instead want to be using `TestFixtureSetUpAttribute`.

You can find the docs for NUnit 2.6.4 here: http://nunit.org/docs/2.6.4/docHome.html

Comment: I modified the Specflow generated  .cs file as [NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureSetUpAttribute] but after editing the feature file 
and rebuild the solution [NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureSetUpAttribute] is replaced with [NUnit.Framework.OneTimeSetUpAttribute]? 

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: @John I'm afraid I don't know anything about Specflow...only NUnit. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

In NUnit 2.6.4, a `SetUpFixture` used `SetUpAttribute` and `TearDownAttribute`. This changed to `OneTimeSetUpAttribute` and `OneTimeTearDownAttribute` in NUnit 3. The hange that @Chris refers to also took place, but it affects`TestFixture` not `SetUpFixture`.

Answer (score 0):

`OneTimeSetUpAttribute` exists in the NUnit 2.6.5, the docs can be found here: http://nunitsoftware.com/nunitv2/index.php?p=onetimeSetUp&r=2.6.5

So the first thing you can try is to update the NUnit NuGet package.
If you are using SpecFlow it won't make sense to edit the SpecFlow generated files because they will be re-generated again by the SpecFlow.

the best thing would be to start using new NUnit 3.x and the new SpecFlow package.